Algorithm to extend function $f(x,y)$ to orthogonal curvilinear coordinate system
Given a (sufficiently nice) function $f(x,y) : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, how would one find a function $g(x,y)$ such that $(f,g)$ form a 2-D orthogonal curvilinear basis (i.e. if the contour lines $f(x,y)=c$ and $g(x,y)=c'$ intersect, then they are perpendicular)?
In particular, given a black box function which can evaluate $f(x,y)$ at any $(x,y)$ (e.g. a neural network), I want an algorithm to compute $g(x,y)$ at any $(x,y)$.
Partial progress: If $f(x,y)$ is a harmonic function, i.e. $\triangle f=0$, then $g(x,y)$ is the harmonic conjugate which can be computed by solving the Cauchy-Riemann equations. However sometimes $f(x,y)$ may not be harmonic, e.g. $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$. (In this case, I think $g(x,y)=\arctan(y/x)$ works?)

As soon as the map $(x,y)\mapsto (f,g)$ is invertible you have your coordinate system at least for the range of this map. There is no need to require that contour lines are perpendicular.

I explicitly want the coordinate system to be orthogonal, in the sense that the contour lines are perpendicular. For example if $f(x,y)=x$, then I would want to find $g(x,y) = y+c$. I just edited the question to state this.

What derivative operation on $f$ gives you a vector that is perpendicular to the contour line $f(x,y)=c,?$ Ditto for $g,.$ What condition for the Jacobian of $(f,g)$ now follows?

I assume you are implying that the Jacobian matrix $J(x,y)$ has to be invertible at all $(x,y)$. But how would you use that condition to determine $g(x,y)$ only given $f$?

To satisfy your requirement the Jacobian has to be orthogonal. Your own example in a comment shows that $g$ cannot be uniquely determined given $f,.$

I am fine with $g$ not being uniquely determined. I just want an algorithm that can give me any $g(x,y)$, given $f(x,y)$.

Given $f$ we find $g$ whose gradient is orthogonal to that of $f$ by the ansatz $\partial_xg=\partial_yf\,,\partial_yg=-\partial_xf\,.$ By the Poincare lemma: On any simply connected domain in $\mathbb R^2$ such a $g$ exists iff the one-form $\omega=(\partial_yf)\,dx-(\partial_xf)\,dy$ is closed (and therefore exact). That is:  iff $\partial_y^2f+\partial_x^2f=0$ holds (in other words iff $f$ is harmonic). The algorithm to find this $g$ is to calculate the line integral
$$
g(x,y)=\int_\gamma\omega
$$
where $\gamma$ is a curve that connects a fixed starting point $(x_0,y_0)$ with $(x,y)\,.$
When $f$ is not harmonic the more general ansatz
\begin{align}
\partial_xg&=h\,\partial_yf\,,&\partial_yg&=-h\,\partial_xf
\end{align}
should work. Here $h$ is a non zero function that makes the form
$$
\omega=(h\,\partial_yf)\,dx-(h\,\partial_xf)\,dy
$$
exact. This is also known as integrating factor.
In your non-harmonic example $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ we have
\begin{align}
\partial_yf&=2y\,,&\partial_xf=2x\,.
\end{align}
A known integrating factor is
$$
h(x,y)=\frac1{x^2+y^2}
$$
which leads to the closed form
$$
\omega=2\frac{y\,dx-x\,dy}{x^2+y^2}\,
$$
which is exact only in simply connected domains of $\mathbb R^2$ that do not contain the origin. This is a frequently discussed example.

Thanks! This is really useful. I was wondering if you knew of any ways to approximately compute the integrating factor h. In my situation, I can compute f at any point (x,y), as well as its partial derivatives. (For some context, I am writing code where I just want to compute g on a fine grid, given f(x,y) on the grid )

@UthsavChitra Write out the condition that $h$ is an integrating factor. This gives a first order linear PDE for $h,.$  Solving this approximately on a grid should be easy.

Hm so in practice, it seems pretty hard to estimate $h$ for the function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$. The PDE relies on $\partial h / \partial x, \partial h / \partial y$, which blow up for $h(x,y)=1/(x^2+y^2)$ and are hard to estimate. Moreover even small changes in the integrating factor $h$ lead to inaccurate estimates of $g(x,y)$. But nevertheless this is probably the best approach I have to estimating $g$...

@UthsavChitra Not surprising in this example. Look at what you called contour lines around the origin.
